# creating dynamic component names in react with typescript 3.2.2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've upgraded to typescript 3.2.2 and this code which used to compile is now not compiling:

```
export const Heading: React.SFC<HeadingProps> = ({ level, className, tabIndex, children, ...rest }) => {
  const Tag = `h${level}`;

  return (
    <Tag className={cs(className)} {...rest} tabIndex={tabIndex}>
      {children}
    </Tag>
  );
};
```

With the error:

> Property 'tabIndex' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little late and tested on TypeScript 3.4:

Replace

```
const Tag = `h${level}`;
```

with

```
const Tag = `h${level}` as "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
```

I'm still not sure about `tabIndex`, but now TypeScript can infer other properties like `children`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little verbose, but I've been able to get everything to cleanly compile with full typing by doing it this way:

```js
const H = (
  props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>,
    HTMLHeadingElement
  >
): JSX.Element => React.createElement("h" + this.props.size, props);
```

Then you can use `<H>` in your component and use the `size` property to dictate with heading tag to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use React.SFC.
I have used the React component just like:

```
export default class Heading extends React.Component<Props, {}>
```

maybe you will use the below code, I think you will find the solution:

```
interface HeadingProps {
    tabIndex: any,
}

    export const Heading: React.SFC<HeadingProps> = ({ level, className, tabIndex, children, ...rest }) => {
      const Tag = `h${level}`;

      return (
        <Tag className={cs(className)} {...rest} tabIndex={tabIndex}>
          {children}
        </Tag>`enter code here`
      );
    };
```

and also need to define the tabIndex in level class.

my code:

```
import Level from './component/level';
interface HeadingProps {
    className: string,
    tabIndex: any,
}

export default class Heading extends React.Component<HeadingProps, {}>{
render(){
 const {className, tabIndex}
 return (
        <Level className={cs(className)} {...this.props.rest} tabIndex= 
          {tabIndex}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Level>
      );
    };
}


interface Props {
    tabIndex: any,
}

export default class Level extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
render(){
   return (
            <h1 tabIndex={tabIndex}>
              {this.props.text}
            </h1>
        )
   }
}
```